# Erlang: Trying to generate sets of monitors that only monitor 10 child processes

Tags: concurrency, erlang

So the idea is that we need to take in a number of child processes to spawn/monitor, but we need to spin up monitor processes such that they only deal with less than 10 child processes at a time. So if we take in 35 child processes, we'd need to have 4 monitors, 3 that monitor 10 children, and one that monitors 5.

The problem is that I'm struggling to figure out why the code I've written for this purpose fails. Here's the code:

```
-module(watcher).
-import(sensor, [start/0]).
-export([start/1, stop/0]).

start(NrSlaves) ->
    MasterPids = [],
    MasterPid = spawn(fun() -> master_starter(NrSlaves, MasterPids) end),
    register(master, MasterPid),
    ok.

stop() ->
    master ! die,
    ok.

slave_pid_to_nr(SlavePid, SlavePids) ->
    slave_pid_to_nr(SlavePid, SlavePids, 1).

slave_pid_to_nr(SlavePid, [SlavePid | _Tail], SlaveNr) ->
    SlaveNr;

slave_pid_to_nr(SlavePid, [_Head | Tail], SlaveNr) ->
    slave_pid_to_nr(SlavePid, Tail, SlaveNr + 1).

slave_change_pid(OldSlavePid, NewSlavePid, SlavePids) ->
    lists:map(
      fun(Pid) ->
          if
              Pid == OldSlavePid ->
                  NewSlavePid;
              true ->
                  Pid
          end
      end,
      SlavePids
    ).
%This is the part that errors out
master_starter(NrSlaves, MasterPids) ->
    if (NrSlaves/10) =< 1 ->
        MasterPids = MasterPids ++ [spawn_link(fun() -> master_start(NrSlaves) end)];
    true->
        MasterPids = MasterPids ++ [spawn_link(fun() -> master_start(10) end) || lists:seq(1, (NrSlaves/10))],
        master_starter(NrSlaves-10, MasterPids)
    end,

    receive
        die ->
            io:fwrite("Monitor: received die~n"),
            lists:foreach(fun(MasterPid) -> MasterPid ! die end, MasterPids)
    end.

master_start(NrSlaves) ->
    process_flag(trap_exit, true),
    io:fwrite("monitor: started~n", []),
    SlavePids = [spawn_link(fun() -> slave_start(SlaveNr) end) || SlaveNr <- lists:seq(1, NrSlaves)],
    master_loop(SlavePids).

master_loop(SlavePids) ->
    receive
        die ->
            io:fwrite("Monitor: received die~n"),
            lists:foreach(fun(SlavePid) -> SlavePid ! die end, SlavePids);
        {SlaveNr, Measurement} ->
            io:fwrite("Sensor# ~p measures ~p~n", [SlaveNr, Measurement]),
            master_loop(SlavePids);
        {'EXIT', SlavePid, _Reason} ->
            SlaveNr = slave_pid_to_nr(SlavePid, SlavePids),
            io:fwrite("Monitor: Sensor ~p with PID ~p died because of a crash~n", [SlaveNr, SlavePid]),
            NewSlavePid = spawn_link(fun() -> slave_start(SlaveNr) end),
            NewSlavePids = slave_change_pid(SlavePid, NewSlavePid, SlavePids),
            master_loop(NewSlavePids)
    end.

slave_start(SlaveNr) ->
    % SlavePid = lists:nth(SlaveNr, SlavePids),
    io:fwrite("sensor ~p with PID ~p: started~n", [SlaveNr, self()]),
    %%slave_loop(SlaveNr).
    sensor:start(SlaveNr).
```

I'm getting errors like: "Error in process <0.573.0> with exit value: {{badmatch,[<0.574.0>]},[{watcher,master_starter,2,[{file,"watcher.erl"},{line,39}]}]}"

Any help would be appreciated. It's very close to being finished, but I just need to understand why this isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three problems I see in your code.

Variables are immutable, and `MasterPids = MasterPids ++ ...` will fail with `badmatch` error.  Try assigning to new variable like `NewPids` or `MasterPids2`.

You are missing generator in you list comprehension.  You should have `<-` somewhere there, like `[spawn_link( ... ) ||  _ <- lists:seq(1, (NrSlaves/10)).`

`lists:seq` do not takes floats.  You have to round up `NrSlaves/10` to integer.  You could use [ceiling function from here](https://erlangcentral.org/wiki/index.php?title=Floating_Point_Rounding) (maybe simplify a little, since you won't use negative numbers).

Answer (score 0):

Variable are not mutable in erlang. so

```
MasterPids = MasterPids ++ [spawn_link(fun() -> master_start(NrSlaves) end)];
```

will fail since you try to modify MasterPids